# Microsoft CAL licensing require for users accessing application using JBoss

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I have gone through the presentation and many websites for Microsoft CAL licensing but still need clarification on below Question.

If we go for a standard edition and using IIS to host our Website, 200 Users will be accessing this Website over HTTP protocol and 2 users will be accessing this web server using RDP for configuration / maintainace.

In above scenario, how many Client Access Licenses will be required?

If we go for a standard edition and using JBoss Application Server to host our Website, 200 Users will be accessing this Website over HTTP protocol and 2 users will be accessing this web server using Remote Desktop Protocol for configuration / maintainace.

In above scenario, how many Client Access Licenses will be required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Licensing questions are really best answered by the vendor

Comment: Each server allow 3 RDP connection for maintenance (2 normal and 1 console). Don't have to pay for that. Much different from server in RDP application mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only need to purchase CALs for the number of AD users(if no AD, local users) that are accessing the server(s).

Basicly you are only buying a license for each Windows authenticated user that accesses the server (if it's User CALs you have purchased) no matter which protocol they are using (http, RDP, local, Samba etc.)

And as always, best way is to call Microsoft [directly](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus), select Business customer (most languages this is the 3rd option) and then licensing inquieries(most languages this is the 1st or 2nd option)

Comment: Thanks Erik, That answers my questions very clearly.

Note: I tried contacting Microsoft but got even more confusing answer.

Comment: If you are a partner, it could we worth contacting partner service instead since they tend to go a step beyond to answer your questions. Though CAL Licensing is a confusing topic, even to many MS employees. (I worked for Microsoft on the VL department and took me a great deal of time to understand it fully)